# Why I get this error for my NPM modile in .net core project with Typescript?

Tags: typescript, asp.net-core, npm, webpack, .net-core

What could be wrong in my Typescript configuration, as it is working okay without TS?
Or may be the problem is in my .d.ts file? Do I need it for webpack?

I have a simple NPM module:

index.js:

```
var MyMathTS = function(a, b){
    this.sum = a + b;
};
exports = MyMathTS;
```

index.d.ts:

```
declare class MyMathTS {
    constructor(x: number, y: number);
 sum(x: number, y: number) : number;
}
```

This is my code in main.ts:

```
import "mymathts16";

var mm = new MyMathTS(2, 3);
console.log(mm);
```

The result from webpack is this:

```
/******/ ([
/* 0 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

var MyMathTS = function(a, b){
    this.sum = a + b;
};

exports = MyMathTS;




/***/ }),
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, __webpack_exports__, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(__webpack_exports__, "__esModule", { value: true });
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_mymathts16__ = __webpack_require__(0);
/* harmony import */ var __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_mymathts16___default = __webpack_require__.n(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_mymathts16__);

var mm = new MyMathTS(2, 3);
console.log(mm);


/***/ })
/******/ ]);
```

But I get this error in the console:

[image]

In Angular it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my problem with exporting with **export default MyMathTS**.